# R: Plot: Re-arranging the order of variables

Tags: r, plot

I want to create a barplot in R. However, I would like to re-arrange the variables on the x-axis, not by frequency but by 'meaning'.

Imagine I have the following data set:

```
df<-data.frame(read.table(header=TRUE, text="
ID  Radio
1   A
2   B
3   A
4   C
5   D
6   D
7   E
8   E
9   A
10  B
11  C
12  E
13  C
14  A
15  D
16  A
17  C
18  A
19  A
20  F
21  A
22  C
23  C
24  A
25  B
26  A
27  C
28  A
29  B
30  C"))
```

I want to use `plot` to depict the frequencies.

```
plot(df$Radio)
```

Obviously, R will create a barplot, ordered by the levels of the factor `df$radio` (i.e. `A` `B` `C` `D` `E` `F`). Let us, however, assume, the order should be: `C` `E` `B` `A` `D` `F`. (In the real-case case behind this scenario the variable `dr$radio` stands for the the last time the respondent has been using a radio. `C` stands for 'today', `E` for 'last week' etc.)

I am not sure what to do to re-arrange the order in my barplot. I tried to re-arrange the order of levels of df$radio. However, it just messed up the factor variable. Also, I tried to solve the problem by using `order' in my plot-code but to no avail, too. Any ideas? Much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried converting to `factor` with `levels` specified?

Comment: @akrun, do you mean `factor(x , ...., ordered = is.ordered(x), ...)`? Cheers for the quick reply!

Comment: Yes, in `factor`, set `ordered = TRUE` and specify `levels` in the order you want them.

Comment: I meant `plot(factor(df$Radio, levels=c("C", "E", "B", "A", "D", "F")))`

Comment: can I call you genius? It is exactly what i need. I was stuck on `order`. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `factor` with `levels` specified

```
plot(factor(df$Radio, levels=c("C", "E", "B", "A", "D", "F")))
```